# Use a progressable bar graph when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[img1 http://friedpanseller.com/images/img.png](http://friedpanseller.com/images/img.png)

```
<button id="englishA" class="select" type="button">Select</button>ENGLISH - ADVANCED<br />
<h2>Total: <span id="total">0</span></h2>

var units=0;
document.getElementById('englishA').onclick = function() {
    units=units+2;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = units;
};
```

I want to make a simple graph that goes up by 2 units when certain buttons are pressed (some buttons only make it go up 1 unit). Is there a simple CSS or jQuery way to do it?

Also, when a button is pressed it changes to remove, if 'remove' is pressed 2 units is deducted from the graph and the original button appears again.

Comment: Is it two units for every button or is it like if I press the top most button, the units should be maxed?

Comment: It's two units for every button, but a few buttons only 1 unit